# How to get specific span's value from div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div and i want to get text of a specific span from that div.
Following is my Div code:

```
'<div class="dvDynamic_' + pid + '"><p hidden="true">'+pid+'</p><span class="count_' + pid + '">' + count + '</span><span id="pname" style = "margin-left:70px;">' + pname + '</span><span id="punitprice" style = "margin-left:150px;">' + uprice + '</span></div>'
```

and i want to get text of the following span:

```
<span class="count_' + pid + '">' + count + '</span>
```

Please help me how to do it .

Comment: thanks all for your help !

Comment: don't forget to upvote my question ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span element which you want to target have next sibling with id. you can target that element using id selector and traverse to required span using `.prev()`:

```
$('#pname').prev().text()
```

Comment: yup... i scrolled a bit more when checking the dom in question.

Comment: @user3772251: glad it helps :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar don't forget to upvote my question ):

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `pid` of the span you want to get, you can use

```
$('.count_' + pid).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify `pname` element using ID selector then use `.prev()` to identify the desired `span`

```
$('#pname').prev().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` you can get value of `span` through `div`

```
function findSpanValue(pid){
    return $(".dvDynamic_"+pid).find(".count_"+pid).text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get span element to target have next sibling with id. you can get that element using id selector and traverse to required span using .prev():

```
$('#pname').prev().html();
```

or

```
$('#pname').prev().text();
```